# What is stristr function?

Tags: javascript

I have been searching all over, can't seem to understand this function.  I posted my javascript code on code review and someone edited my code for me and I am just trying to learn from it.

Here is the part I don't understand, its a function but the function wasn't called anywhere in the script, I thought all functions have to be called.  I would just like to understand this code step by step.  Maybe could someone even give me an example on how to use it and where in the script to call it.

```
function stristr (haystack, needle) { 
    var pos = 0 
    haystack += '' 

    pos = haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf((needle + '').toLowerCase()) 
    if (pos >= 0) return haystack.substr(0, pos) 
}
```

Comment: No, not all functions have to be called. Just like not all words in a dictionary have to be used. The function is a replication of a function in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)

Answer (score 1):

Line 1: fcn declaration

Line 2: Define pos variable as 0

Line 3: More or less type cast as string

Line 5: Set position equal to the location in the string of the character represented by needle

Line 6: If the needle exiists in the haystack, return the entire string prior to the needle.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php), you can see that the php version of the function 'Returns all of haystack starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end'. That means given the string (or haystack) 'thisisthehaystack' and the term we're searching for (needle) 'the', the stristr function would return the string 'thehaystack'. The function you posted is similar in that it searches the haystack for the needle, but then returns the substring which starts at the first character and ends at the point in which the needle is found, or 'thisis'.

Comment: The needle will only be found if it exists in the haystack followed by a space, so in the example given by @ryanbwork searching 'thisisthehaystack' for 'the' would fail. Searching 'this is the haystack' for 'the' would return would return the string 'this is '.

Comment: actually, now that I look at it the needle + '' doesn't add a space, probably just casts the needle as a string.

Comment: Fair call - your eyesight is better than mine.